# ActiveMQ message contains NULNULNUL#

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue

ActiveMQ message contains NULNULNUL# sending over /api/message or user interface GUI.

Please help

Comment: You need to post some code.

Comment: there is no code. You can send the message over User Interface to  ActiveMQ Queue for example xml: <MyMessage messageId="123"/>  and then consumer gets message NULNULNUL#<MyMessage messageId="123"/>

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ? How about some screenshots of the UI you're using?